# Adding css class names to the contents of Cells in a gwt CellTable

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable

I want to add style classes to elements in a cell (or the td itself) that will change depending on the state of the data in the cell.  For example, the cell might have color: red when the data is unsaved, color: blue while the data is being saved, and color: black once the save completes successfully.  Code external to the `Cell` will need access to change the class names, once callbacks are fired, etc.

I have achieved something like this with a hack in my `Cell` that gets the `Element` from onBrowserEvent and adds attributes there.  I can set the initial style in `render` and then change it as needed in `onBrowserEvent`, and even keep track of that element so that external code can use it.  This is incomplete, because I can't get the element until onBrowserEvent is called, and annoyingly hacky because I have to set the style in two different places.

What's a better way to achieve this effect without re-rendering the entire table whenever the state of a cell changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The disappointing answer here is that you can't have the best of both worlds - static, all-at-once-rendering, AND dynamic, change-one-element-updating.  The only way to change the style of a single cell, within the methods provided by `CellTable` et al, is to rerender the whole table.

In my own code I've kind of formalized the hacks I made to update single cells at a time, by setting the DOM id of a `div` rendered to each table cell.  Then I can use `getElementById` and proceed from there.  I still avoid the overhead of a full widget.  It's a little clunky, but hidden behind a nice interface it's not too bad.

Answer (score 1):

I found something like

```
table.setRowStyles(new RowStyles() {
@Override
public String getStyleNames(Contact row, int rowIndex) {
    if (row.name.startsWith("J")) {
        return "bold";
    } 

    return null;
}
});
```

which should work in GWT 2.4 to resolve your matter.